# react-native, Android emulator and local subdomains

Tags: networking, react-native, android-emulator

recently I'm finding my way into react-native and I'm stuck with some local routing.

I run a Rails API Server that uses subdomains, which are routed by my host-file. eg: company.thy.me is redirected to localhost.

Under iOS it's no problem, because the Simulator uses the same interface then the Mac does. I can set my apiUrl to company.thy.me:3000/api and can reach the server with no problem.

Under Android things get tricky, because Android uses 10.0.2.2 to communicate with the Mac and therefor I can't call the subdomain directly.

What can I do here?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? We have exactly the same problem. Rails + subdomain + hosts file + 10.0.2.2

Comment: The best solution I had that time was to pull the hosts file from the android emulator via adb, change it and push it back to the emulator. You have to do that every reboot.